# POST references response

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I'm having some difficulties to get a "urn" response from a "POST references" request. I receive only a:

```
{"result": "success"}
```

As specified in the API Documentation, the Body Structure (200/201) has to return a "result" ("success") **and** a "urn" (urn identifier of the source file).

How can i get the urn response ?

An I missing something in the request? The API Documentation says : "To use it with the POST job endpoint, you need to set checkReferences to true." I see no Attribute "checkReferences" in POST job request Body Structure.

Thank you

Comment: The first time you run the REST Call will give you that 201 Success. Try running it again and the status will be 200 with the JSON data of the reference. Be patient since you might have quite a lot of date coming back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replied to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48648062/uploading-linked-revit-models-to-autodesk-forge/48649334#48649334). Take also a look at the end, there is a note about malformed payload being a bug and returns success.